# Reading content from .html file with content type xml

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to read content from .htm file with content type of xml but it always gives me unexpected output. I'm trying with `htmlagility` pack and `System.IO.File.ReadAllText`.

the output which I get from `htmlagilitypack` or `File.ReadAllText` is same.

output of reading text from .htm file

[image]

Comment: looks like this file is binary?

Comment: First open file with a normal editor to see if it is really htm, if so then probably encoding issue, try different encoding while using ReadAllText method (for example ASCII)

Comment: Using Xml linq : StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml string);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(sReader);

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add the code in question to the post so we can help you.